# asynchronous notification in VBA

Tags: vba, asynchronous, notifications

I'm currently trying to write a script that requires a notification bar in the form. The script itself is responsible for creating invoices, which works so well. However, I want to display errors and information in a label. The label is already in a frame and I have the following code as well:

```
    Private Function notificate(msg As String, Optional title As String)
        lbl_notification.Caption = msg

        If Not IsEmpty(title) Then
            frm_notification.Caption = title
        Else
            frm_notification.Caption = ""
        End If

        frm_notification.Visible = True

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

        frm_notification.Visible = False

        frm_notification.Caption = ""
        lbl_notification.Caption = ""
        notificate = True
    End Function
```

(I am not sure if it should be a subroutine or a function.)

How do I get this function to work so that I can use my form at the same time, if that is possible?

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224308/non-blocking-toast-like-notifications-for-microsoft-access-vba

Comment: Just to make you aware: The verb that corresponds to the noun *notification* is *to notify*. (The word you chose will likely be understood just as well, it just sounds a little funny.)

Comment: @inarion ohh ^^ thanks for that. Yeah i'm sorry if there are some errors. I'm from germany

Comment: No need to feel sorry. We all make mistakes. And improvements mostly come from practicing. So keep doing that. :)

Comment: And regarding your actual question: I highly recommend checking out the link @Andre posted above. Trying to achieve it in native VBA would involve a lot of messy `Application.Run` calls, I guess.

Comment: I did, but it did't really help. So I've tried a few things and have finally done it ^ ^ I'll comment the solution right back to the question

Comment: I realized after having a look at the repository that linked question points to that there is no source code available... As such I can't really recommend it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried it a bit and finally got it done. Meanwhile, my subroutine looks like this:

```
    Private Sub notificate(msg As String, Optional title As String)
        ofEvent = False

        lbl_notification.Caption = msg
        If Not IsEmpty(title) Then
            frm_notification.Caption = title
        Else
            frm_notification.Caption = ""
        End If

        frm_notification.Visible = True
        frm_notification.Transparency = 0.5

        For i = 1 To 1000000
            DoEvents
            If ofEvent Then
                GoTo GoOn
            End If
        Next i

    GoOn:

        frm_notification.Visible = False

        frm_notification.Caption = ""
        lbl_notification.Caption = ""
    End Sub
```

And as you can already imagine, the following is in my frame in the click function

```
    ofEvent = True
```

And ofEvent is a global boolean Variable