# How to open a timed Message Box in MS ACCES without creating additional window

Tags: vba, ms-access

On pressing a `Save` button on a `form`, I would like to run a Timed Message Box that closes automatically after 1 second. The default `MsgBox` command does not disappear until user presses `OK` or `Exit`.

So far, I have a solution from online search:

```
Public Sub Timed_Box (dur AS Long)

Dim WSH AS IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
Dim Res AS Long

Set WSH = IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell

Res = WSH.PopUp(Text:="Record Updated", secondstowait:=dur, _ 
Title:="Update", Type:=vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

It works fine. However, the problem is that it creates a temporary Window on desktop Taskbar for the duration which is quite annoying for a user to see. Is there anyway, I can hide this window from appearing on taskbar while still display message similar to `MsgBox`?

Comment: Have a look at this instead of MsgBox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224308/non-blocking-toast-like-notifications-for-microsoft-access-vba

Comment: @Andre, it looks very promising. I spent some time to make sense of it but I do not know how to load the .dll library to my Access project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an additional answer instead of just a comment, because it seems to be too important to the requested context.

Lone wrote regarding MatteoNNZ's answer:

> > Thanks for sharing, the result is no different from what I am achieving with my existing code. Your code also produced a Temporary Window on taskbar.

---

But it's just a small step away from your needs!

Just provide the handle of your Microsoft Access Window (`Application.hWndAccessApp`) to the Api to let the resulting message box be 'visually bound' to Microsoft Access:

```
MsgBoxTimeout Application.hWndAccessApp, "This message box will be closed after 1 second ", "Automatically closing MsgBox", vbInformation, 0, 1000
```

## Update 2019-04-05

Here is a wrapper for the MessageBoxTimeout to simplify the calling.

The order of the parameters and their default values follow the original `MsgBox` function.

It uses the original API function namens to free this name for the user defined procedure.

I added an enumeration for the timeout return value `32000`.

You should take care to add proper error handling.

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxTimeoutA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, ByVal wlange As Long, ByVal dwTimeout As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, ByVal wlange As Long, ByVal dwTimeout As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Enum VbMsgBoxTimeoutResult
    Timeout = 32000
End Enum

'// If parameter msgTimeoutMilliseconds < 1 then the message box will not close by itself.
'// There is one additional return value to the values of VbMsgBoxResult:
'// If the message box timed out it returns 32000 (VbMsgBoxTimeoutResult.Timeout).
Public Function MsgBoxTimeout(ByVal msgText As String, Optional ByVal msgButtons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, Optional ByVal msgTitle As String = vbNullString, Optional ByVal msgTimeoutMilliseconds As Long = 0) As VbMsgBoxResult
    MsgBoxTimeout = MessageBoxTimeoutA(Application.hWndAccessApp, msgText, msgTitle, msgButtons, 0, msgTimeoutMilliseconds)
End Function
```

An usage example:

```
Select Case MsgBoxTimeout("Foo", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Bar", 5000)
    Case VbMsgBoxTimeoutResult.Timeout
        Debug.Print "MessageBox timed out."
    Case vbYes
        Debug.Print "User selected 'Yes'."
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "User selected 'No'."
End Select
```

Comment: Great! This works like a charm... Just one more favor, do you know how can I turn off the notification sound when this message pops-up?

Comment: I expect that would only be possible in the settings of the operating system (Windows), so it would be system wide.

Comment: Alright, than it will be a pain to handle. Btw, Could you conceive of a way to make `'Application.hWndAccessApp` as part of `MsgBoxTimout` function so that I don't have to type it when calling the `custom MsgBox` function across `modules/ classes`?

Comment: I added a wrapper and a sample call for you to my answer.

Comment: Cool. Selected as answer!

Answer (score 1):

An option is to create your own messagebox. This you can open with a timeout:

```
' API call for sleep function.
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


Public Function OpenFormDialog( _
    ByVal FormName As String, _
    Optional ByVal TimeOut As Long, _
    Optional ByVal OpenArgs As Variant = Null) _
    As Boolean

' Open a modal form in non-dialogue mode to prevent dialogue borders to be displayed
' while simulating dialogue behaviour using Sleep.

' If TimeOut is negative, zero, or missing:
'   Form FormName waits forever.
' If TimeOut is positive:
'   Form FormName exits after TimeOut milliseconds.

    Const SecondsPerDay     As Single = 86400

    Dim LaunchTime          As Date
    Dim CurrentTime         As Date
    Dim TimedOut            As Boolean
    Dim Index               As Integer
    Dim FormExists          As Boolean

    ' Check that form FormName exists.
    For Index = 0 To CurrentProject.AllForms.Count - 1
        If CurrentProject.AllForms(Index).Name = FormName Then
            FormExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If FormExists = True Then
        If CurrentProject.AllForms(FormName).IsLoaded = True Then
            ' Don't reopen the form should it already be loaded.
        Else
            ' Open modal form in non-dialogue mode to prevent dialogue borders to be displayed.
            DoCmd.OpenForm FormName, acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, OpenArgs
        End If
        ' Record launch time and current time with 1/18 second resolution.
        LaunchTime = Date + CDate(Timer / SecondsPerDay)
        Do While CurrentProject.AllForms(FormName).IsLoaded
            ' Form FormName is open.
            ' Make sure form and form actions are rendered.
            DoEvents
            ' Halt Access for 1/20 second.
            ' This will typically cause a CPU load less than 1%.
            ' Looping faster will raise CPU load dramatically.
            Sleep 50
            If TimeOut > 0 Then
                ' Check for time-out.
                CurrentTime = Date + CDate(Timer / SecondsPerDay)
                If (CurrentTime - LaunchTime) * SecondsPerDay > TimeOut / 1000 Then
                    ' Time-out reached.
                    ' Close form FormName and exit.
                    DoCmd.Close acForm, FormName, acSaveNo
                    TimedOut = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        ' At this point, user or time-out has closed form FormName.
    End If

    ' Return True if the form was not found or was closed by user interaction.
    OpenFormDialog = Not TimedOut

End Function
```

It does, however, take a lot more code to obtain the full functionality of a messagebox, but it is carefully described and for download in my article:

[Modern/Metro style message box and input box for Microsoft Access 2013+](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17684/Modern-Metro-style-message-box-and-input-box-for-Microsoft-Access-2013.html)

Code is also at **GitHub**: [VBA.ModernBox](http://Modern/Metro%20style%20message%20box%20and%20input%20box%20for%20Microsoft%20Access%202013+)

Comment: Well, I am unable to access GitHub from my company laptop due to security constraints.

Comment: Oh. Then use the _Expert Exchange_ link. It has attached a zip with a demo and all code as well.

Comment: I tried that first but it is not available for free. Signing up requires  a subscription and I can't afford to pay for it. So far, I have been learning VBA-Access through open sources only.

Comment: There is a link at that page like "click here to gain access to the full article". Or, try this [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmcbXlHdG3aahfgzoqeooLGgcRerUA) to my OneDrive folder.

Comment: Thanks Gustav for continuous support. It works indeed. The complete code is rather too much for me to handle but I will take it as a base point to design a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MsgBoxTimeout` function provided in the library `user32` of Windows.

Declare the following on top of your module:

```
#If Win64 Then 'If the system is in 64b
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MsgBoxTimeout _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
            ByVal wlange As Long, _
            ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
    As Long
#Else 'if it's in 32b
    Private Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
            ByVal wlange As Long, _
            ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
    As Long
#End If
```

Then use it like this:

```
MsgBoxTimeout 0, "This message box will be closed after 1 second ", "Automatically closing MsgBox", vbInformation, 0, 1000
```

Some useful notes:

- The `#If Win64 Then` part is a macro determining at compile time what declaration to use. In 64b systems, in fact, every function declared by an external library should use the `PtrSafe` (pointer-safe) keyword which doesn't exist in 32b systems.
- You pass the timeout in milliseconds, that's why the parameter is `1000` when you want it to wait 1 second.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, the result is no different from what I am achieving with my existing code. Your code also produced a Temporary Window on taskbar.

Comment: @Lone, you need to keep in mind that VBA runs on a single thread process, and that the MsgBox is designed to wait the user action before it closes down. There is literally no way to have a MsgBox and another process which shuts down the MsgBox within the same thread, you will necessarily need 2 threads (one showing the MsgBox and another one closing it down) and Office applications are not designed to do that, so it is impossible not to have another process (the one you mention as being a window on the taskbar) to do what you try to do.

Comment: @Lone, if I can ask, why is this other process opening up for few seconds an issue for you, knowing that it will be shut down after 1 second?

Comment: Well, for me, even MsgBox was doing a great job. But my boss wants the app to behave like a  web interface where if an action is performed a small notification pops up and then closes automatically. Your explanation makes sense, let me try to convince my boss on this issue.

Comment: @Lone otherwise, if really this additional window is an issue, then you will have to code your application in a real programming language (for example C# which already offers easy interactions with Access databases) and in there you will be able to have 2 threads into the same application - the point is, does it really make sense to migrate an entire application not to see an additional program opening for one second into the taskbar?

Comment: Actually, I am not a programmer by profession. I took this task of app development as a challenge on myself to get familiarizes with database and coding structures. I considered VBA and Access as an easy starter pack. Now, when I am asked to develop new functionalities in the app, I never know when I should say 'No' since I take it as my lack of knowledge. I believe learning C# and code entire thing again will not be possible in next two week when my deadline ends to finish the app.

Comment: @Lone in this case, I think your best shot is to go with one of these solutions (either the one you already have, or the one I proposed). The MsgBox stays open for just 1 second, that's the time you'll have your "temporary window" appearing in the taskbar. I think it's really a minor price to pay to have a multi-threaded solution into a VBA application (p.s. by the way, this doesn't happen on my computer... what is this temporary window looking like?)

Comment: I could have posted a pic but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do so. It is just like an icon you see while opening Access file.  It flashes on the taskbar while you work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my wrapper for MessageBoxTimeout to simplify the call. Instead of returning timeout information, I needed to **return the default button** value. The order of parameters and default values follows the original MsgBox function for better use.

```
Option Compare Database

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxTimeoutA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, ByVal wlange As Long, ByVal dwTimeout As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, ByVal wlange As Long, ByVal dwTimeout As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Enum vbMsgBoxTimeoutResult
    vbTimeout = 32000
End Enum

'// If parameter msgTimeoutMilliseconds < 1 then the message box will not close by itself.
'// The default timeout is set to 15 sec
'//
Public Function MsgBoxTimeout(ByVal msgText As String, Optional ByVal msgButtons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, Optional ByVal msgTitle As String = vbNullString, Optional ByVal msgTimeoutMilliseconds As Long = 15000) As VbMsgBoxResult

   'Always set minimal timeout to 1 sec
    If msgTimeoutMilliseconds < 1000 Then msgTimeoutMilliseconds = 1000

    MsgBoxTimeout = MessageBoxTimeoutA(Application.hWndAccessApp, msgText, msgTitle, msgButtons, 0, msgTimeoutMilliseconds)
    
    'timeout action
    If MsgBoxTimeout = VbMsgBoxTimeoutResult_Timeout Then
        
        Dim defaultButtonFlag
        
        'get default button
        defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton1
        If msgButtons And vbDefaultButton4 Then defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton4
        If msgButtons And vbDefaultButton3 Then defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton3
        If msgButtons And vbDefaultButton2 Then defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton2
        
        'get only buttons information
        msgButtons = msgButtons And 7

        'return default value
        If msgButtons = vbYesNo Then
            
            If defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton2 Then
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbNo
            Else
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbYes
            End If
            
        ElseIf msgButtons = vbYesNoCancel Then
            
            If defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton3 Then
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbCancel
            ElseIf defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton2 Then
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbNo
            Else
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbYes
            End If
        
        ElseIf msgButtons = vbAbortRetryIgnore Then
            
            If defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton3 Then
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbIgnore
            ElseIf defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton2 Then
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbRetry
            Else
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbAbort
            End If
    
        ElseIf msgButtons = vbOKCancel Then
         
            If defaultButtonFlag = vbDefaultButton2 Then
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbCancel
            Else
                MsgBoxTimeout = vbOK
            End If
        
        ElseIf msgButtons = vbOKOnly Then
        
            MsgBoxTimeout = vbOK
            
        Else
        
            'do nothing, already MsgBoxTimeout = vbMsgBoxTimeoutResult.vbTimeout
        
        End If
        
    End If
    
End Function
```