# How to make a self closing pop-up warning in access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a pop-up message that the user doesn't need to close when the mouse is on a button for more than a half of second (without clicking it, just pointing on the button), also I want it to close itself after a second or two...

I've tried with msgbox function but I was unable to make it self-closing.
Also, is it possible to make that message appear if the mouse is on a button for a while without clicking it?

Comment: Are you referring to a 'Tip' box that helps give additional information if they hover?  You can set this property for the control in the 'ControlTip Text' property of the button.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are looking for tooltips (see above). Or if you want to control it with code, maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224308/non-blocking-toast-like-notifications-for-microsoft-access-vba