# How to debug a C# code written for an Excel Formula and running in Release mode?

Tags: c#, excel-formula

I have written an Excel Formula using C# by following this link: [Canonical: How to call .NET methods from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074533/canonical-how-to-call-net-methods-from-excel-vba)

Now, I had to run the project in release mode to use the formula in Excel. But somehow it is causing some error and I can't understand it. So I thought of debugging my code using breakpoints.

But as this is in Release mode, the breakpoints, quite naturally, doesn't hit. How should I debug the C# code then? Is there any possible solution?

(I am writing the code for the formula in the C# end and not in the VBA. Please mind that.)

I have tried running the code in Debug mode but then the formula doesn't come.

Comment: The project is building successfully. But there is some problem in the logic of the formula which is not yielding a correct result.

And about "how" I am doing it, please refer to the link properly and see the accepted answer, second point.

Comment: You can look into this link. I think it will help you understand what I am trying to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288909/how-to-pass-a-range-object-in-an-excel-formula-created-through-c


Don't go through the question. Rather look into the code associated with the question. I hope you will get your answers.

Comment: My requirement is creating an Excel addin which will create few tables on some inputs. Then I have to create a separate Class Library which will create an .XLL file and can be used as an Excel formula which will help me parse and work with the tables.

Comment: I don't understand why are you focusing on what I am trying to do, rather than answering the actual question though. The addin is nowhere related to this formula project.