VB Net Excel Automation Addins using VS 2022
I’m having problems getting some Chip Pearson VB.NET script for an excel automation to run on VS2022 (http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AutomationAddIns.aspx) – see script below:
Imports Microsoft
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComVisible(True)>
Public Class Division
    Public Function DivideBy2(ByVal D As Double) As Double
        Return D / 2
    End Function

    <ComRegisterFunctionAttribute()>
    Public Shared Sub RegisterFunction(ByVal type As Type)
        Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(GetSubkeyName(type))
    End Sub

    <ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute()>
    Public Shared Sub UnregisterFunction(ByVal type As Type)
        Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(GetSubkeyName(type), False)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetSubkeyName(ByVal type As Type) As String
        Dim S As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        S.Append("CLSID\{")
        S.Append(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper())
        S.Append("}\Programmable")
        Return S.ToString()
    End Function
End Class

I create a Class Library(.NET Framework) and insert Chip’s script, then install and add a references to the Microsoft and System.Runtime.InteropServices libriaries via Imports, and sign the code within the Properties Tab.
The Addin is a simple User Defined Functions that divide its inputs by 2. Because VSTO’s can not create this type of Add in ( I have tried) I have had to debug the function manually. After successfully compiling the code into a dll file, I register it using RegAsm.exe on a DOS cmd prompt.
Then I open excel and go to File-> Options-> Add-In but the Add-In does not appear in either list ( Active or Inactive).
If I try to load it manually by selecting COM Add-in in the combo box at the bottom and hitting Go, then Add in the next Dialogue box , I get a message saying

"C:\ XXX .dll"  is not a valid Office Add-in.

The script works perfectly on older versions of VS ( i.e.  before 2005).
After many days research I seem to be running around in circles. Just wondering if anyone might has any ideas. My code probably needs addition instructions or interface but I am unable to find a similar working example. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Here you go, read through method 2 and then you'll be able to see what I've done that the Pearson example is missing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39199922/495455, use a Converter from C# to VB.Net - for a start I can see you're missing  [Guid("A44BF1F2-483F-48F9-8A2D-4DA68C53C13B")] 

Thanks Jeremy. I'll give that a go.
