# Order of appearance on data created from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office

I have created a code for reporting. The code generate the output in following order.

```
Less Than 35 Lakhs
35 Lakhs to 75 Lakhs
3cr to 5cr
75 Lakhs to 1Cr
1cr to 3cr
5cr to 10cr
10crs and above
```

but i want following order.

```
Less Than 35 Lakhs
35 Lakhs to 75 Lakhs
75 Lakhs to 1Cr
1cr to 3cr
3cr to 5cr
5cr to 10cr
10crs and above
```

Is there something obious i am missing in the code ?

```
Sub LoanBucket1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NewWs As Worksheet
    Dim LoanRange As Range
    Dim provisionRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Loan As Double
    Dim provision As String
    Dim Bucket As String
    Dim summaryDict As Object
    Dim currentTime As String
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim grandTotalLoan As Double

    ' Set the source worksheet to the current sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Prompt user to select Loan range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set LoanRange = Application.InputBox("Select the range for Loans", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If LoanRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Operation canceled. Please run the macro again and select a valid range.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Prompt user to select provision range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set provisionRange = Application.InputBox("Select the range for provisions", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If provisionRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Operation canceled. Please run the macro again and select a valid range for provisions.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check if the number of rows in both ranges is the same
    If LoanRange.Rows.Count <> provisionRange.Rows.Count Then
        MsgBox "Error: The selected ranges must have the same number of rows.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Get current time to use in the sheet name
    currentTime = Format(Now, "hh_mm_ss")

    ' Add a new worksheet with a name based on current time
    On Error Resume Next
    Set NewWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If NewWs Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error creating the new sheet.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    NewWs.Name = "Summary_" & currentTime

    ' Headers for the new sheet
    NewWs.Cells(1, 1).value = "Bucket"
    NewWs.Cells(1, 2).value = "Total Loan"
    NewWs.Cells(1, 3).value = "No of Loans"
    NewWs.Cells(1, 4).value = "NPL Amt"
    NewWs.Cells(1, 5).value = "No of NPLAcs"
    NewWs.Cells(1, 6).value = "No of NPL /TotalAcs%"
    NewWs.Cells(1, 7).value = "NPL%"
    NewWs.Cells(1, 8).value = "% of Loan"  ' New column header

    ' Bold the header row
    With NewWs.Rows(1).Font
        .Bold = True
    End With

    ' Find the last row with data in the Loan range
    lastRow = LoanRange.Rows.Count

    ' Create a dictionary to store the sum and count of Loans for each bucket
    Set summaryDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    summaryDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' Case-insensitive

    ' Loop through each row and categorize the Loans into buckets
    For i = 1 To lastRow ' Assuming the data starts from the first row

        ' Get the Loan and provision category from the selected ranges
        Loan = LoanRange.Cells(i, 1).value
        provision = provisionRange.Cells(i, 1).value

        ' Determine the bucket
        If Loan < 3500000 Then
            Bucket = "Less Than 35 Lakhs"
        ElseIf Loan < 7500000 And Loan >= 3500000 Then
            Bucket = "35 Lakhs to 75 Lakhs"
        ElseIf Loan < 10000000 And Loan >= 7500000 Then
            Bucket = "75 Lakhs to 1Cr"
        ElseIf Loan < 30000000 And Loan >= 10000000 Then
            Bucket = "1cr to 3cr"
        ElseIf Loan < 50000000 And Loan >= 30000000 Then
            Bucket = "3cr to 5cr"
        ElseIf Loan < 100000000 And Loan >= 50000000 Then
            Bucket = "5cr to 10cr"
        Else
            Bucket = "10crs and above"
        End If

        ' Sum and count the Loans in the corresponding bucket
        If summaryDict.Exists(Bucket) Then
            summaryDict(Bucket)("Sum") = summaryDict(Bucket)("Sum") + Loan
            summaryDict(Bucket)("Count") = summaryDict(Bucket)("Count") + 1
        Else
            Dim bucketData As Object
            Set bucketData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            bucketData.Add "Sum", Loan
            bucketData.Add "Count", 1
            bucketData.Add "NPL Amount", 0 ' Initialize NPL Amount to 0
            bucketData.Add "No of NPL", 0 ' Initialize No of NPL to 0
            summaryDict.Add Bucket, bucketData
        End If

        ' Sum the Loans and count the provisions in the corresponding bucket, excluding "Good" and "Watchlist"
        If UCase(Trim(provision)) <> "GOOD" And UCase(Trim(provision)) <> "WATCHLIST" Then
            summaryDict(Bucket)("NPL Amount") = summaryDict(Bucket)("NPL Amount") + Loan
            summaryDict(Bucket)("No of NPL") = summaryDict(Bucket)("No of NPL") + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Calculate the grand total loan amount
    grandTotalLoan = WorksheetFunction.Sum(LoanRange)

    ' Write the summary to the new sheet
    For Each key In summaryDict.Keys
        currentRow = NewWs.Cells(NewWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ' Bucket
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 1).value = key

        ' Sum of Loans
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 2).value = summaryDict(key)("Sum")
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 2).NumberFormat = "#,##0" ' Apply comma style

        ' Count of Loans
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 3).value = summaryDict(key)("Count")

        ' NPL Amount
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 4).value = summaryDict(key)("NPL Amount")
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0" ' Apply comma style

        ' No of NPL
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 5).value = summaryDict(key)("No of NPL")

        ' Calculate percentages
        ' Percentage No of NPL / Count of Loans
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 6).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & _
            NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 5).Address & "/" & _
            NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 3).Address & ",0)"
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 6).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

        ' NPL Amount / Sum of Loans
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 7).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & _
            NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 4).Address & "/" & _
            NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 2).Address & ",0)"
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 7).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

        ' % of Loan
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 8).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & _
            NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 2).Address & "/" & _
            grandTotalLoan & ",0)"
        NewWs.Cells(currentRow, 8).NumberFormat = "0.00%" ' Format as percentage
    Next key

    ' Display totals
    Dim totalRow As Long
    totalRow = NewWs.Cells(NewWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Bold the total row
    With NewWs.Rows(totalRow).Font
        .Bold = True
    End With

    ' Sum of Loans for the total row
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 2).Formula = "=SUM(B2:B" & totalRow - 1 & ")" ' Sum of Loans
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 2).NumberFormat = "#,##0" ' Apply comma style

    ' Count of Loans for the total row
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 3).Formula = "=SUM(C2:C" & totalRow - 1 & ")" ' Count of Loans

    ' NPL Amount for the total row
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 4).Formula = "=SUM(D2:D" & totalRow - 1 & ")" ' NPL Amount
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0" ' Apply comma style

    ' No of NPL for the total row
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 5).Formula = "=SUM(E2:E" & totalRow - 1 & ")" ' No of NPL

    ' Calculate percentages for the total row
    ' Percentage No of NPL / Count of Loans
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 6).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & _
        NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 5).Address & "/" & _
        NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 3).Address & ",0)"
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 6).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

    ' NPL Amount / Sum of Loans for the total row
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 7).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & _
        NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 4).Address & "/" & _
        NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 2).Address & ",0)"
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 7).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

    ' % of Loan for the total row
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 8).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & _
        NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 2).Address & "/" & _
        NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 2).Address & ",0)"
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 8).NumberFormat = "0.00%" ' Format as percentage

    ' Autofit columns in the new sheet
    NewWs.Columns.AutoFit

    ' Name the total row as "Grand Total"
    NewWs.Cells(totalRow, 1).value = "Grand Total"

    MsgBox "Operation completed successfully. Summary created on sheet " & NewWs.Name, vbInformation
End Sub
```

I want the desired order for bucket in the output sheet. I am using office 2016 and 365 both.

Comment: The <= parts of your if statement are redundant.  You can safely delete then.

Comment: You could sort the date before/after writing to the sheet, or create the dictionary before filling if (otherwise the dictionary is created in the order the values appear)

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary doesn't provide any sorted order, so the result is not reliable at all. And even if it was, the sorted order would be alphabetical, no sorting algorithm can guess the order you want.

What you can do is to read the keys of your dictionary into an array, sort this array and then loop over the sorted keys.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14808104/7599798) discussed how you can get a sorted dictionary, but at the end of the day that is overkill as you don't need a sorted (new) dictionay when you have already the sorted keys.

Okay, let's start. This code comes before you write the data to the result sheet:

```
Dim keys(), key
keys = summaryDict.keys
SortArray keys
' Write the summary to the new sheet
For Each key In keys
```

Now we need the `SortArray`-routine. I have choosen Bubblesort because you have only very few entries in the array and borrowed the code from [the internet](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-bubble-sort-macro-to-sort-array/)

```
Sub SortArray(arr)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp As Variant
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            if arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                temp = arr(j)
                arr(j) = arr(i)
                arr(i) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

But wait. This will sort the keys alphabetical because of the check `arr(i) > arr(j)`. We need to find a way to compare two keys to decide which is "smaller" or "greater".

The following function will return a number defining the position of the key in the sorted list. It uses a static array with all the possible keys and the `Match`-function - you could also use a table in a sheet.

In case you pass something that is not defined in the array, the routine will return an arbitrary large number and therefore the key would get sorted at the end.

```
Function getSortPosition(key As Variant) As Long
    Static sortInfo(1 To 10) As String
    If sortInfo(1) = "" Then  ' Array is not yet filled. 
        sortInfo(1) = "Less Than 35 Lakhs"
        sortInfo(2) = "35 Lakhs to 75 Lakhs"
        sortInfo(3) = "75 Lakhs to 1Cr"
        sortInfo(4) = "1cr to 3cr"
        sortInfo(5) = "3cr to 5cr"
        sortInfo(6) = "5cr to 10cr"
        sortInfo(7) = "10crs and above"
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    getSortPosition = WorksheetFunction.Match(key, sortInfo, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If getSortPosition = 0 Then getSortPosition = 99
End Function
```

Now all what is left to do is to replace the compare in the sort function:

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
         If getSortPosition(arr(i)) > getSortPosition(arr(j)) Then
         (...)
         End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: what changes i need to make in the code ? kindly simplify as i am new to vba and non techie. where should i use sortarray routine

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing to simplify. **(1)** For the first few lines: You can identify the place in your code by the comment (`' Write the summary to the new sheet`). **(2)** Put the two new routines wherever you want. **(3)** Run the code and see that the order will be alphabetical. **(4)** Replace the `If`-statement in the sortArray routine and run again.